# R, htmlTreeParse and xml library giving empty list during web-scraping attempt

Tags: r

I am having issue when i use xml library for web scraping.

```
library(XML)
url<- "http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=HI-I6C0AAAAJ&hl=en"
html<-htmlTreeParse(url,useInternalNodes = T)
```

**1st Instance**

```
xpathSApply(html,"//title",xmlValue)
# list()
```

corresponding the html source code 
Jeff Leek - Google Scholar Citations

**2nd instance**

```
xpathSApply(html,"//span[@class='gsc_g_al']",xmlValue)
# list()
```

Corresponding HTML source codes are as below  :
86

**3rd Instance**

```
xpathSApply(html,"//td[@class='gsc_a_ac']",xmlValue)
# list()
```

Corresponding HTML source codes are as below  :
466

Trial 
    xpathSApply(html,"//td",xmlValue)
    list()

The same thing when i use httr library

```
library(httr)
html2 = GET(url)
content2 = content(html2, as="text")
parsedHTML = htmlParse(content2, asText = TRUE)
```

**1st instance**

```
xpathSApply(parsedHTML, "//title", xmlValue)
# [1] "Jeff Leek - Google Scholar Citations"
```

**2nd instance**

```
xpathSApply(parsedHTML, "//span[@class='gsc_g_al']", xmlValue)
# [1] "86"  "129" "106" "185" "285" "435" "573" "669" "658"
```

**3rd instance**

```
xpathSApply(parsedHTML, "//td[@class='gsc_a_c']", xmlValue)
# [1] "466" "457" "444" "245" "219" "198" "173" "158" "142" "129" "110" "73"  "69"  "46"  "29*" "24"  "22"  "20"  "19" 
# [20] "18"
```

i get the desired result

Kindly help i am always getting empty list() with htmlTreeParse and xml library..Is it something to do with my installation of the library ?

Comment: Why not just use `httr` if it works?

Comment: Check the html - you may see a Server Error which means that Google knows you are trying to scrape their site which violates the terms of service.

Comment: I see thanks for the inputs. Yes, I did see the error in the end .. So, i need to learn about the difference in XML libraries and HTTR libraries ... I think its something to do with java script support..But, I am not sure..  It's an irony that google does not like webscraping .. I think they had set out to download the web back in the days :-) ...